# What be these men doing?

Tags: word, knowledge

> A great long line of men stands before you
>
> Occasionally 2 and 3 stand side by side
>
> 1 was a lover.
>
> 1 was extremely funny.
>
> 3 were winners.
>
> 4 were lucky.
>
> 8 were from the city.
>
> 12 were devout.
>
> 13 had done nothing wrong.
>
> 14 showed mercy.

Comment: Are we supposed to determine order?

Comment: A: Standing.  :)

Comment: Wasn't there 3 "winners" ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Could it be referring to:

> Popes

4 were lucky:

> Felix

13 had done nothing wrong:

> Innocent

8 were from the city:

> Urban

12 were devout:

> Pi(o)us

and so on...

Comment: This. This fits perfectly (there's a pope Valentine and a pope Hilarius). And when 2 or three stands side by side, that mus be referring to the three popes years.

Comment: There were also 2 (or 3?) Victors

Comment: Indeed-the other missing ones are those who were lenient or merciful-Clement! That's why they are specifically men-and 2 or 3 standing side by side is where there were antipopes(which also make it quite hard to count them,depending on who you include and don't include)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like

> They were standing at the pearly gates awaiting entry into heaven.

Which makes me

> God (Cool :D)

Explanation

> A great long line of men **stands** before you 
>  AND 
>  Occasionally 2 and 3 **stand** side by side 
>  BUT
>  1 **was** a lover, 1 **was** extremely funny, 2 **were**, 4 **were** .... 
>  The past tense implies they're no longer as they're described. Or they're deceased.

Line by line description

A great long line of men stands before you

> Maybe god is sexist and doesn't allow women? But this is generally how the gates to heaven are described as; a long line of people awaiting entry.

Occasionally 2 and 3 stand side by side

> They died together. Hence await judgement side by side.

Observations from the rest of the lines

> Don't really provide any clues except that there is a wide demographic represented. Suggestive of no correlation between them.
>  
>  A lover, a winner, someone who's funny, are all positive virtues to get into heaven.
>  
>  The lucky ones probably did enough bad in their lives to fear eternity in hell. But got lucky in afterlife.
>  
>  Being devout will certainly allow entry to heaven.
>  
>  The 13 who had done nothing wrong also would be granted entry to heaven.
>  
>  Showing mercy is a heavenly virtue right?

Answer (score 1):

The motto of these standing people

> Journey

They are

> At the airport checking-in. Here, men specify general population not some sexist remark by author (i think so) talking of first 3 persons. First is lover, yearning for his/her love as this journey will take him/her to the lover. Second person is funny as his remarks making people around him to laugh. The next two were happy as they won tickets for this journey from a competition.

Moving to 4, 8 and 12 ones

> These 4 are lucky as they got an unexpected holiday from there college or work and they planned to make most of this time. Next 8 people from this city are travelling somewhere can be seen from there attire or there mood of not being happy of leaving there home. 12 devout embarking on an airplane to go to a religious place

Last two group of people

> 13 had done nothing wrong, it can signify regular travelers or transit persons who were in the city for business meeting or other stuffs. 14 have shown some mercy, a tricky one, these people have given way for excited trip winners, an emotional lover, a jolly person and 8 resigned(not happy but satisfied) traveler and 12 religious people. Enough to put give them a mercy tag i think. ( if something better comes up i will surely pass on).